# Sometimes drive mappings don't connect at logon

Tags: windows, group-policy, mappeddrive

I have this strange problem at all our clients. Sometimes, when u user logs on, a drive-mapping is missing. So for example, the user needs 2 drive-mappings, but gets only one.

We are deploying drive-mappings through GPO. I am aware of these issues:

1. Set Group Policy to always run **synchronously** (explained here: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12221.group-policy-troubleshooting-drive-maps-preference-extension-replace-mode-only-maps-the-drive-every-other-logon.aspx?wa=wsignin1.0)
2. Set policy to **Update**, not Create or Replace. I'm aware that Replace will disconnect and reconnect a drive-mapping in the middle of the day when group-policies are updated.

This problem doesn't happen often. It's only once in months. Sometimes rebooting or logoff/logon might solve the issue, sometimes not. There are no errors or helpful events in EventLog. Sometimes running **gpupdate** causes the drive to connect, sometimes not. All clients are Windows 10, all on local LAN's. In all cases I could just connect the missing drive letter manual with a **NET USE** command.

I did not enable **reconnect** at the drive-mapping policy, but I'm trying that now, however that shouldn't be necessary.
[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is almost completely solved after we changed the following registry-entry on the client:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\lanmanworkstation\parameters\KeepConn
```

Set to **86400** (default is 600 seconds).
More info on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/mapped-drive-connection-to-network-share-lost

[image]